# SQL Reporting Service 2017 in Virtual Server

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2017, ssrs-2017

I am trying to set up Reporting Service 2017 in a VPS. The problem comes when I finish the installation of SQL Reporting Service 2017 and try to access to the Web Service URL. Any of the options possible (by IP, LocalHost, domain name...) give any access to the Report Server, just say that the web address is incorrect.

Did anyone has the same case and know how to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: After the installation you have to configure the service (define service credentials, database, etc.) https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5237/installing-sql-server-reporting-services-2017/

Comment: Yeap, I followed all these steps, everything looks correctly set, but the URL still doesn't connect to the Web Service at all.

Comment: Actually it was a problem with the URL in the server, not related to Reporting Service. The problem has been solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Good to know you have found solution to your problem